# ORACLE: Is table organized by index?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to check with pl/sql if a table is organized by index?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the script below with **USER_TABLES** or **ALL_TABELS** to investigate all tables

```
 SELECT 'IS_ORAGANIZED' FROM DUAL
 WHERE 
 UPPER(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'tableName')) LIKE  '%ORGANIZATION%';
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT IOT_TYPE FROM ALL_TABLES
```